# How to create a page that cycles through a series of websites every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, frames, x-frame-options

I'd like to automatically cycle through a series of URLs every 30 seconds.  For example, imagine Google.com displays for 30 seconds, then it switches over to Stackoverflow.com for 30 seconds, then on to [Zombo.com](http://www.zombo.com) (Where anything is possible).  Perhaps I'll add some sort of cool page transition as well, where the old page *slides* out or something.

My first attempt was to just create a webpage that has a giant `IFRAME` that contains the page:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px;"></iframe>
```

Then, I could use script to change the source every 30 seconds.  However, it seems modern browsers lock all this stuff down pretty tight.  Every URL I've tried gives me the following error:

> > Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

I think, at least for now, we'll be displaying pages we control but I'd rather not muck with a bunch of code or HTTP server settings if I don't have to.

I suppose I could also create a WPF or Silverlight app that hosts a web browser control, then have total control over the browser.

Are there any simpler options for this sort of app?

**Downvoters:**

I'm not quite sure why this was considered a bad question.  For what it's worth, I completely understand why the X-Frame-Options header exists and the reason for security concerns around hosting IFrames across domains.  I'm not looking for ways to counteract legitimate browser security features.  I was simply looking for a good method to rotate through a list of websites automatically, and wondering what a good design for this would be.

Comment: Sites like Google are complaining because they do not allow themselves to be rendered in iframes for security reasons. Look into web components, the `embed` tag, or the `object` tag.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy That didn't work for me, I either got "Plugin not supported" or no `<embed>` or `<object>` at all.

Comment: When you say "Plugin not supported", are you referring to web components? I recommend using a polyfill and trying out web components again.

Comment: Why not **window.open** and _win.location.href_ **OR** _win.location.reload_ ?

Comment: Question is about creating a website but accepted answer is about an extension please update question title to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with browser plugins, rather than fighting with IFRAMEs.

[Rotisserie URL Rotator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rotisserie-url-rotator/iljemanjjfjlglhkmojkmfbpphiaheja?hl=en)

[Revolver Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revolver-tabs/dlknooajieciikpedpldejhhijacnbda?hl=en)

Comment: +1 Or stuff like a Chrome extension that tells if you have been to your website and starts affecting that page if you have.

Comment: Love this!  I wish I could do some sort of page transitions, but I guess it'll do for now.